# Suggestions for SSH Client in Linux Mint

Tags: ssh, linux-mint, remote, openssh, editors

I am using Linux Mint 18.3 on a Dell Laptop.

I like the connect to server feature in my file browser windows which allows me to easily access remote directories via SSH. However, as I repeatedly enter the username, IP and password, I can also see an option that the device will somehow remember these things. But where to retrieve the remembered data? Basically, what to do if I have to regularly log in to 3-4 different machines and do not want to enter the user credentials manually each time?

On the same topic, is there any good and free substitute of MobaX for Linux mint? I tried installing Termius, but the package manager snap seems to fail to do it. (For all other purpose, I use apt-get repository, I installed snap only for Termius and it fails, which is kinda annoying).
Is there any other SSH client that will allow

- Single click Login to remote machines without using SSH command and password on local terminal
- Directly editing codes on the remote (via local editors such as Atom) without going via git or scp etc. just like what MobaX offers on Windows

What's the recommendation?

Answer (score 4):

It is considered bad practice to passwords for SSH.  Instead you create a public/private key pair for your client and register the public key on the server.  You can use an SSH agent (available on linux mint, and MobaX) to load your private key ready for use.

See  [how to set up ssh keys on linux](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys-on-linux-unix/)

The short version is that you create your private key:

```
ssh-keygen
```

Keep the default location.  This will create your private key `id_rsa` and public key `id_rsa.pub`.

Then you copy the contents of your newly created `id_rsa.pub` onto your server... add it to the file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` creating a new authorized_keys file if one doesn't already exist.

---

You really don't need an alternative to MobaX for linux mint.  MobaX is there to mimic what you already have under most linux distributions.  Just open a terminal (command line) and type:

```
ssh user@remotehost
```

By default, MabaX wants to use a key agent and forward the X server to allow you to open windows:

```
# do this once to start the agent and add your private key from ~/.ssh/id_rsa
ssh-add

# Then to connect to your server
ssh -AX user@remotehost
```

*remember to replace `user` and `remotehost` which your actual details.*

---

Based on your comment there are a couple of other tools to look into:

- Mint should have an equivalent to windows shortcuts (most likely named "launchers", though I'm not a mint user).  You should be able to create one which automatically opens a terminal running ssh to your favourite host.
- Filezilla - This will let you work with SCP and drag and drop files  to / from your server
- SSHFS - This will go further and let you mount SCP letting you edit files on your server in your favourite editor

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, quoting from your answer 'Just open a terminal (command line) and type', is the stage I was hoping to automate with a single click. Another functionality of MobaX is I can just open a code file from the file-browser window with local editor such as VS Code, edit and save. It will be instantaneously updated on the remote. I know, a shell ninja can probably be more productive doing this with Vim, but I like the ease of Mobax and wish I could do it on a Mint or Ubuntu desktop.

Comment: Okay I've edited, I think you'll find using a terminal more intuitive than you believe for basic SSH access.  Definitely checkout SSHFS as this will let you use VS Code directly with files on a remote file system over SSH.

Comment: You can also use the remote development plugin for VS Code, just to offer yet another alternative solution: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a desktop shortcut that opens an SSH session in a terminal emulator for you. No need for another SSH client.

First of you'll still want to create an SSH keypair, like @Philip Couling suggests. It's more secure than a password, and you won't have to type it in every time you connect (One of the few cases where the convenient solution is also more secure).

Create a new file on your desktop with a file name ending in `.desktop`.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application    
Name=SSH    
Exec=gnome-terminal -e "/usr/bin/ssh username@remotehost"    
Terminal=false
Categories=Network
```

Make sure to change `username@remotehost` for the actual details. Feel free to change the `Name` and `Categories` fields to suit your needs. You can see the list of available categories [here](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/latest/apa.html), and a list of the other options available [here](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#recognized-keys)

If you want it to show up in your applications menu, you can install the shortcut using `sudo desktop-file-install myserver.desktop` (Changing myserver.desktop to the name of the file you created).

You can probably make this file in a more clever way, but I don't use Mint or GNOME, so I wouldn't be able to test it. If someone can make it better, feel free to edit in your improvements.

For additional information on desktop entries, you can check out this Arch Wiki page: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_entries

Answer (score 1):

Since the time I asked the question, I found the open source client called [Remmina](https://remmina.org/how-to-install-remmina/) which is already included with Ubuntu and can be installed easily on other distributions.

In addition, I also got familiar with mounting remote file systems via SSHFS.

So it seems a combination of these two tools meets my requirements perfectly (going beyond my expectation) and thought I would post this as an answer in case any other noob like me is looking for advice.